# Exclude overwritten classes for an element in LESS

Tags: html, css, less

Mechanism I have to work with, that is not changable:

Page is rendered with some styles on them eg. class xy.

Some html is generated dynamically and injected into:

```
<div id="InternalContent"> /* injected here */ </div>
```

by CSS is applied by doing:

```
#InternalContent {
/* .less files here */
}
```

The goal is to be able to render some elements inside #InternalContent with original classes, not overwritten by #InternalContent.

I tried:

```
#InternalContent:not(.NotInherited) { ... }
#InternalContent:not(*:not(.NotInherited)) { ... }
```

and some others, but to no success.

The only way this works is if the classes themself have :not(.NotInherited).

```
#InternalContent .xy:not(.NotInherited) { }
```

but in my case there are far to many classes to change manually for this to be an acceptable solution.

Smallest (not) working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/nvhouq1k/

HTML:

```
<p class="xy">This to be orange</p>

<div id="InternalContent">
  <p class="xy">This to be blue</p>
  <div class="NotInherited">
    <p class="NotInherited xy">This to be orange</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.xy {
    color: orange;
}

#InternalContent:not(*:not(.NotInherited)) .xy{
  color: blue;
}
/* *:not(.NotInherited) */
/* :not(.NotInherited) */
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your `not()` selector so that it only targets `.xy` elements: You can try the following:

```css
.xy {
    color: orange;
}

#InternalContent .xy:not(.NotInherited) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="xy">This to be orange</p>


<div id="InternalContent">
  <p class="xy">This to be blue</p>
  <div class="NotInherited">
    <p class="NotInherited xy">This to be orange</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there are hundred classes that I would have to do this for. The goal is to have :not(.NotInh) to be add in some kind of a loop or somehting in #InternalContent { }

Comment: Find and replace to the rescue. CSS has no parent selector, so this is one of the only solutions.

Comment: I was hoping maybe there is a way in LESS to add this at the end of each class or some other trick :(

Comment: To add what? It sounds like you need to explain your question better.

Comment: to add :not(.NotInherited) at the end of each class that is being rendered in #InternalContent { /* .less files */ }. Eg. that xy that is in one of the less files comes out as xy:not(.NotInh...)

Comment: @cantdoanything33 What's wrong with `#InternalContent *:not(.NotInherited)`?

Comment: It should be "#InternalContent *:not(.NotInherited) .xy {...}" which does not work. "#InternalContent *:not(.NotInherited) {...}" is invalid because in general all the elements inside #InternalContent should have .xy overwritten. There is an exception that an element of class .NotInherited inside #InternalContent should have .xy with original styles (not overwritten by #InternalContent).